# Using bracket for automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

What is the difference between `(ab)*` and `[ab]*` when we write in Automata regular expression? In my opinion, they both mean *ab* zero or more times, but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), they differ as follows:

- For square brackets (`[ ]`) **you pick only one of the characters**:

> Matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. For example, `[abc]` matches *"a"*, *"b"*, or *"c"*...

- For round brackets (`( )`) **characters are grouped together to act as a single entity**:

  (Quote slightly adapted)

> Defines a subexpression. It is treated as a single element. For example, `ab*` matches *"a"*, *"ab"*, *"abb"* and so on, while  `(ab)*` matches "", *"ab"*, *"abab"*, *"ababab"*, and so on.

Therefore, `(ab)*` works as you said, producing *"ab"* zero or more times.

But `[ab]*` would likely mean "either "*a*" zero or more times, or "*b*" zero or more times". In other words, `(a*)|(b*)`.